# How many elements are there in $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question

It is easy to verify that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ forms a group with $+$ operation and $\mathbb{Z}_5 \setminus \{[0]\}$   with $\times $ operation. I know that there are infinite elements in $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Question:** How many elements are there in $\mathbb{Z}_5$? Is it $5$ or finite? I know it is a group of order $5$ so it should have $5$ elements, but I also know that there will be classes and in each there will be infinite elements. I am always confused in these things.

Comment: But what is $\mathcal Z_5$?

Comment: You should use standard notation for this group $\mathbb£

Comment: Maybe you mean the group $\mathbb Z_5$ ?

Comment: Rebellos Yes I have edited the question

Comment: Yes thanks@rebellos

Comment: @shi.  In this group one class represents one element in this group, like all integers multiple of 5 represent one element namely [0], hence there are only 5 such classes so there are only five elements in this group

Comment: *Even  if each element of $\mathbb Z_5$ is a set with infinitely many elements, $\mathbb Z_5$ as  a set has  five elements, which are the five sets. In short,  the number of elements $\mathbb Z_5$  contains, reflects in absolutely no way, the nature of its elements*. If I  have a bag with seven cats each having seven kittens, and I create the set of all such bags, then  the size of such  a set is $7$, because  we don't care about the  fact that the bags have forty nine kittens each. That doesn't make  the size of  the set $7 \times 7 \times 7$   ,does it?

Comment: Maybe this analogy would be helpful: Think of a big bag containing five small bags. The small bags are each filled with sand. How many "elements" does the big bag have? Answer: Five. These are the five small bags. Each of these small bags have a "roughly infinite" number of elements: the sand particles.

Comment: @Shahab Really cool hands-on example !

Answer (score 1):

There are $5$ elements in $\Bbb Z_5$ (which by the way is not a group with $\times$, although $\Bbb Z_5\setminus\{[0]\}$ is). Each of those five elements is an infinite set of integers.

Comment: Thanks for the correction that $\mathbb{Z}$ does not make group with $\times$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the multiplicative group of integers modulo $5$ is the following group :

$$\mathbb Z_5 = \{\bar{0}, \bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3},\bar{4}\}$$

Hence, there are $5$ elements in it, also denoted by the order of it, $|\mathbb Z_5| = 5$. Now, regarding your question about each element, it's true that each one of the elements elaborated in the expression of $\mathbb Z_5$ consists of a set of infinite integers.

Take notice, that $\mathbb Z_5$ is a group with the operation $+$. A group with the operation $\times$ regarding a group of integers modulo $5$, would be $\mathbb Z_5 \setminus \{\bar{0}\} = \mathbb Z_5^*.$

Comment: It would be better to say "infinite set of integers" rather than "set of infinite integers".

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there are $n$ number if it is an additive group and it is:
$$\mathbb{Z}_n=\left\{\bar{0}, \bar{1},\dots,\overline{n-2},\overline{n-1}\right\}$$

Instead if it is a multiplicative group there are $\phi(n)$ elements, where $\phi(\cdot)$ is the [Euler’s totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) and it is:
$$\mathbb{Z}^*_n=\left\{\overline{a}\in\mathbb{Z}_n|\gcd(a,n)=1\right\}$$

In your case $\mathbb{Z}_5$ as an additive group is made of 5 elements and it is 
$$\mathbb Z_5 = \{\bar{0}, \bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3},\bar{4}\}$$
As a multiplicative group it has cardinality $\phi(5)=4$ and it is 
$$\mathbb Z_5^*= \{\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3},\bar{4}\}$$

One one hand there are only a limited number of elements. On the other hand there are unlimited number on element inside because you group them in base of the remainder with the division modulo $n$.

In fact there are, for example, infinite numbers $k\in\mathbb N$ such as $k\equiv 1 \pmod n$.